# How can I run an example in cloudsimSDN?

Tags: java, sdn, cloudsim

I can't run the CloudSimSDN via cmd (Command Prompt) and I can't run that via eclipse, too.
I installed eclipse 4.6.0, JDK 1.8.0. The cloudSimSDN needs CloudSim-3.0.3, apache Commons Math, json-simple-1.1.1 and guava-17.0. 
I have given below the errors. Could you tell me know what needs to be done?

When I try to execute the example using the following command:

```
 java -cp ./*:.  org/cloudbus/cloudsim/sdn/example/SDNExample MFF dataset-energy/energy-physical.json dataset-energy/energy-virtual.json dataset-energy/energy-workload.csv > results.out
```

`java -cp ./*:.`This code needs to be write in special directory? Or `-cp ./*:.` is a special switch in java?(please explain about it. I am beginner in cloudsim,  Help me please.

Below are the error codes:
Could not find or load main class org.cloudbus.cloudsim.sdn.example.SDNExample.

My reference of source code: [CloudSimSDN](https://github.com/fogony/cloudsimsdn/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: what happens when you try  to run it in eclipse?

Answer (score -1):

please go through steps mentioned here at tantrabhavan.blogspot.com. It worked for me!!!!